# How to transfer a vector from Python to R (and back) after having done some R specific computations

Tags: python, r, vector, environment-variables, rpy2

Let's say I have a vector `x1` as a numpy array in the python environment. I want to transfert that vector to the R environment, do some computations using R specific functions and then get another vector `x2` and then want to transfer `x2` back to python as a numpy array. The goal is to have the following output:

```
[1 2 3]
[2 2 3]
```

Here is a code (which works until the line 9 but not after) using rpy2 (or any other package)?

```
from rpy2.robjects import FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr('stats')
base = importr('base')
#lmtest = importr("lmtest")
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1,2,3])
print(x1)
robjects.r('''
        x2 = x1  
        x2[1] = x2[1] + 1 ## some R specific function
        ''')
print(x2)
```

**EDIT**

I tried to implement the answer of @lgautier as follows:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1,2,3])
print(x1)
robjects.r('''
           x2 = x1  
           x2[1] = x2[1] + 1 ## some R specific function
           ''')

x3 = robjects.r['x2']
```

but I got the following error message

```
R[write to console]: Error in (function (expr, envir = parent.frame(), enclos = if (is.list(envir) ||  :
  object 'x1' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `pyper`

```
from pyper import *
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1,2,3])
r = R(use_pandas=True)
r.assign('x1', x1)
expr1 = '''x2 = x1;
         x2[1] = x2[1] + 1;
         x2'''
r(expr1)
r.get('x2')
```

-testing on python

```
>>> from pyper import *
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x1 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> r = R(use_pandas=True)
>>> r.assign('x1', x1)
>>> expr1 = '''x2 = x1;
         x2[1] = x2[1] + 1;
         x2'''
>>> r(expr1)
'try({x2 = x1;\n+          x2[1] = x2[1] + 1;\n+          x2})\n[1] 2 2 3\n'
>>> r.get('x2')
array([2, 2, 3])
>>>
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer @akrun. I tried your code but get the following error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyper_try01.py", line 7, in <module>
    r.assign('x1')
TypeError: __setitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'`

Comment: @ecjb sorry, a mistake.  it should be `r.assign('x1', x1)`

Comment: ok many thanks @akrun. Now when I run the new code, python is running in terminal without ending (without error message in the terminal, like in an infinity loop). Do you know what could happen?

Comment: @ecjb is your package installed correctly

Comment: So @akrun I reinstalled the package with `pip install PypeR` and ran `pip install --upgrade pip` and with the command `pip freeze` I got (among other)`PypeR==1.1.2`. To me it sounds like it's installed. I'm running macos `11.2.3`

Comment: I also tried to create a new python virtual environment with only numpy and pyper install without any improvement: the program is running forever without any output

Comment: I used to run pyper successfully earlier.  My anaconda is kind of frozen.  So, I have to restart it to test

Comment: I did a software upgrade in mac and thus my anaconda is having some issue

Comment: Oh! so you mean you have the same problem @akrun?

Comment: @ecjb it is a different problem which is basically with anaconda.  I will test it outside anaconda

Comment: @ecjb There was a typo.  the last one should be `r.get('x2')`. Now it is working for me.  Please check my update

Comment: @ecjb Sorry, I was careless earlier.  Usually, I test a code, but this time I didn't notice the issue at the last line. thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

In the following part of your code you declare a **Python** variable `x1` to which you assign a numpy array. R will not know about it until you create an R to variable (optionally with the same name).

```
x1 = np.array([1,2,3])
# Python knows about x1, you defined it right above.
print(x1)
# R does not know any x1 unless you have defined it before.
robjects.r('''
           x2 = x1  
           x2[1] = x2[1] + 1 ## some R specific function
           ''')
```

To define `x1` in the R global environment, try:

```
robjects.globalenv['x1'] = 123
```

The introduction in the documentation covers this here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html#the-r-instance

Besides that, converting from and to `numpy` array requires the use of a converter. `rpy2` can function with or without `numpy`. The documentation is here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/numpy.html

Comment: Dear @lgautier. Many thanks for your answer. I tried first to find a solution with `rpy2` because I had the impression that the package was much more updated and there was a rich documentation. I also saw that you are one of the main maintainers of the package. Thank you very much for the writing of the package. However, althouth I tried to read this rich documentation, I could not find the answer to my specific question. Could you help me on this. I'm happy to post a new question if you want

Comment: Dear @lgautier. I again tried your code edited the question accordingly but I still could not get the code functionning. Could maybe please tell me what am I missing? Many thanks in advanece!

Comment: The variable `x1` is declared on the *Python* side. The embedded R has no way to know that there is a variable called like that on the Python side. I am editing the answer to add one way to resolve this.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @lgautier. I'll try to implement this solution next time I'll run into a similar problem.